# Find $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\pi^{x\ln x} - 1}{x}$ if it exists .

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f(x) = \frac{\pi^{x\ln x} - 1}{x}$ . Find $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x)$ if it exists .

**My try** : $f(x) = \frac{\pi^{x\ln x} - 1}{x} = \frac{e^{x\ln x \ln \pi} - 1}{x}$ . Using $(\forall u\in\mathbb{R}):e^u=1+u+\frac{u^2}{2!}+\frac{u^3}{3!}+\cdots$ and putting $u = {x\ln x \ln \pi} $ leads to $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x) = -\infty$ . I'm not sure whether or not my answer is right . Also I'm looking for other solutions .

Comment: I think what you have is correct and the most direct method.

Comment: @Paul Yes , the answer was $-\infty$ again but it can't guarantee that  $-\infty$ is true .

Comment: @Clayton Okay , thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer is right.

Since $x\ln{x}\rightarrow0$, we obtain:$$\frac{\pi^{x\ln{x}}-1}{x}=\frac{e^{x\ln{x}\ln\pi}-1}{x\ln{x}\ln\pi}\cdot\ln\pi\ln{x}\rightarrow-\infty$$

Comment: Thanks , I think $\pi$ should be $\ln \pi$ .

Comment: @S.H.W You are welcome! It was typo.

Comment: How we can prove $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) = \infty$ if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \infty$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W We can do it by the definition of the limit. Try it. It's not so hard. I am ready to show, but open please another topic.

Comment: Okay , I will try to prove . Thanks again .